# loading local json file into content script of chrome extension

Tags: json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest, content-script

We all know that content script of chrome extension has limitations, But it also allows to parse json data through XMLHttpRequest. I wanted to know how?

Here i've the data in json file, assume it as

### links.json

```
{"list1":[
  {"alt": "text1", "link": "img1.jpg"},
  {"alt": "text2", "link": "img2.jpg"},
  {"alt": "text3", "link": "img3.jpg"}
]}
```

Content-script file

### script.js

```
function dip() {

var JSONFile_url = chrome.extension.getURL("links.json");
// JSONFile_url is set to "chrome-extension://[extensionID]/links.json"

var linkarr;    

var JSON_req = new XMLHttpRequest();
JSON_req.overrideMimeType("application/json");
JSON_req.open('GET', JSONFile_url, true);
//JSON_req.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

JSON_req.onreadystatechange = function()
{
    if( JSON_req.readyState == 4 )
    {
        linkarr = JSON.parse(JSON_req.responseText);
```

> everything goes fine until this point. 
>                   But JSON.parse is not working as expected & 
>                   linkarr remains with undefined value.

```
    }
}
JSON_req.send();

//... some additional code goes here..

mm=document.createElement("div");
mm.appendChild(document.createTextNode(linkarr));
d.appendChild(mm);    //appends tag in html page

//... some additional code goes here..

}

dip();  //calling main function...
```

### manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Simple content script extension",
  "version": "3.0",

  "icons": {
    "256": "icon.png"
  },

  "permissions": ["http://*.somehost.com/*"],

  "content_security_policy": "connect-src 'self'; script-src 'self'; object-src 'self'",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*.somehost.com/*"],
      "css": ["script.css"],
      "js": ["script.js"],
      "run_at": "document_end"
    }
  ],
  "converted_from_user_script": true,
  "web_accessible_resources": ["links.json"]
}
```

### Output

```
Undefined
```

Now i've 3 options here,

1. debug the above code to get the array/object list from json
   data/file.
2. use the xhr code in background javascript page.
3. make a javascript file & store the json data into a variable & include it in the content_scripts under manifest.json to access that
   variable.

Please help me to go with the 1st option here. OR any other working method will be fine.

> **Note:** This code is under content script of chrome extension. for more refer this
>   https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts
>   https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy

Comment: Hi Rob W, I tried all solutions found on stackoverflow & groups.goggle.com. But didn't got the working code yet. please help me with answer or give me the link of previously asked question that has been answered.

Comment: The link to the question is currently at the very top of your answer. I agree with the duplicate fully - and that's a very good canonical question that is linked as duplicate, it should help you.

Comment: Thank you Xan!. And thanks Rob W!. Got it working after analyzing the asynchronous vs. synchronous factor. I changed the code with the callback function similar to this one http://codepen.io/KryptoniteDove/blog/load-json-file-locally-using-pure-javascript